# How to get the Last Modified date of all files in a folder using Batch

Tags: dos

Suppose i have a folder which contains 5 files.
I want to run a batch script which outputs all the filenames in the folder along with the last modified dates.
The output has to be written as a text file.

The output should be as follows:

- Sample1.xls 4/7/2011
- Sample2.xls 3/6/2011
- Sample3.xls 5/4/2011
- Sample4.xls 2/4/2011
- Sample5.xls 6/2/2011

Answer (score 3):

From the commandline:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b') do @echo %a %~ta
```

This outputs:

```
D:\temp\modtime>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data1
 Volume Serial Number is 925B-DC37

 Directory of D:\temp\modtime

06/28/2012  05:03 PM    <DIR>          .
06/28/2012  05:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/28/2012  05:02 PM                 2 a.txt
06/28/2012  05:03 PM                 2 b.txt
               2 File(s)              4 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,485,646,065,664 bytes free

D:\temp\modtime>for /f %a in ('dir /b') do @echo %a %~ta
a.txt 06/28/2012 05:02 PM
b.txt 06/28/2012 05:03 PM
```

Make the % into %% to put it in a batch file.  If you don't need the times, you can post-process to get rid of them.

Answer (score 2):

You should  use dir command i think dir *.* /o-d 
have look to this linke [MSDOS DirCommand](http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm)

also you can create a text file and put the command in the file and save it as .bat file

if you read the link you will see there are many option
check this one

```
dir *.* /o-n-d /b
```

Comment: Actually i need only the Name of the files and the last modified dates of each file in that folder. But the command that u suggested displays all the details..

Comment: I tried the command that u suggested. But it just displays the file names. I am not getting the Last modified date.